# Open in Java(TM) Platform SE binary

Tags: java, file, file-io, filehandle, file-locking

I tried to delete a file that I have two of, one slightly changed, so I could delete the older one and replace it with the new one I changed. When I tried to delete the file I got the error message 'file in use' where it said the action can't be completed because the file is open in Java(TM) Platform SE binary.

How do I close it?

Comment: check if a java process is running - if its holding onto a file lock, you might want to kill the java process (I am assuming this is a test box you are using and not some production server).

Answer (score 96):

This is what worked for me (using Windows). It is basically the same procedure as commented by ali haider, but with more details...

Using Windows command prompt:

```
tasklist | findstr java
```

("findstr" is a command line utility for Windows similar to "grep" in Linux)

Search for any lines with 'java' and note the PID of the java process.

```
taskkill /F /PID "PID_OF_JAVA_PROCESS"
```

where "PID_OF_JAVA_PROCESS" should be replaced with actual PID number.

Result:

```
SUCCESS: The process with PID "PID_OF_JAVA_PROCESS" has been terminated.
```

Repeat for each java process that is running. Now you should be able your desired file!

Let me know if you need instructions for Linux (i.e. ps, kill, etc.), but probably most Linux users know these...

Comment: This worked for me, on Windows 10. I would usually go to Task Manager and end the process. But this time it wasn't present in the Task Manager processes either.

Comment: Much easier to just do: `taskill /im java.exe /f`. Achieved the exact same result for me

Comment: @Recessive just a typo in your command - `taskkill /im java.exe /f`

Answer (score 28):

Simply open the task manager on Windows, Check for Processes, Close all the java processes.
Now again try deleting the file, you should be able to.
This worked for me.

Cheers!

Comment: did not work for me, whenever i was deleting the java process another java process was immediately created and it was taking 1 gb of memory, instead, I restarted the windows and problem was solved

Answer (score 4):

Close the project in Eclipse and it should work.

Comment: Android Studio in my case

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 8.1:

1) Start Menu...choose "Run" and type: msconfig  and click "OK".

2) "System Configuration" opens  click the "Startup" tab.

3) Click where it says "Open Task Manager".

4) Choose the "Processes" tab.

5) Look through the list and find "Java SE". Right click and choose "End Task".

6) Close "Task Manager" and "System Configuration" box.

7) Go back to file that could'nt be deleted. Right click and choose "Delete" again. Presto........file deleted.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Task Manager in windows.
2. Go to view-> Select Columns and check command line.
3. Now kill the java process that locked the file.
   (command line option shows the path of the java proces from where it gets executed so that unnecessarily you don't need to kill all the java process.)

Comment: did not work for me, whenever i was deleting the java process another java process was immediately created and it was taking 1 gb of memory, instead, I restarted the windows and problem was solved

Comment: Update: I didn't see a View option for Select Columns but you can right-click on the tab and it's one of the options. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If it's not something that runs during a system boot, try rebooting to clear all open files.

Comment: One would assume there is some other solution than rebooting (which is annoying for simply closing an open file)!

Answer (score 1):

-Open Task Manager
-Go Details Tab
-Find Name=java.exe and  CommandLine= your jar path
-Right Click
-End Task

Example:
Name         Command line
javaw.exe   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "C:\TEST\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"